# Subgroup of commutators of generators

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

My target is to prove that, in order to abelianize a group, it sufficies to take the subgroup generated by the commutators of the generators instead of the commutators of the whole group, to make the factor group.

I checked he answers in here [The generator set of the commutator subgroup of a free group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510055/the-generator-set-of-the-commutator-subgroup-of-a-free-group), but there's something that doesn't convince me at all in the last answer (the one given by SundayMorning).

He has proved that $K = [G, G]$ is the least **normal** subgroup that contains $Y$, the set of the commutators of the generators. However I don't see why $K = \langle Y \rangle$, because it's not clear for me that $\langle Y \rangle$ is normal.

The definition I know of $\langle H \rangle$ states that it's the least subgroup containing $H$, not necessarily normal.

Comment: It would be helpful if you made this more self contained and it would probably also get more attention.

Comment: If you look at the first answer you'll see what you are trying to prove is not true.