# Proof of the universal property of free abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, abelian-groups, free-groups

> Let $S$ be a set. The group with presentation $(S, R)$ , where $R = \{\ [s , t] \mid s,t\in S\ \}$ is called the *free abelian* group on $S$ -- denote it by $A (S)$ . Prove that $A (S)$ has the following universal property: if $G$ is any abelian group and $\varphi:S\to G$ is any set map, then there is a unique group homomorphism $\phi : A (S) \to G$ such that $\phi\mid_S=\varphi$ . Deduce that if $A$ is a free abelian group on a set of cardinality $n$ then
> $$
> > A\cong\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}\ \ (n\text{ factors})\ .
> > $$

For all $N\unlhd G$ containing $R$ , we have $[s,t]\in R\subseteq N$ , then $[s,t]N=N$ , and so
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \,[s,t]\langle R\rangle&=[s,t]\bigcap_{R\subseteq N\unlhd F(S)}N
 \\&=\bigcap_{R\subseteq N\unlhd F(S)}N
 \\&=\langle R\rangle\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
 st\langle R\rangle&=ts\langle R\rangle
 \\s\langle R\rangle\,t\langle R\rangle&=t\langle R\rangle\,s\langle R\rangle
\end{aligned}
$$
implies $F(S)/\langle R\rangle$ is abelian.

Denote $F(S)'$ the commutator subgroup of $F(S)$ . Let $\pi':F(S)\to F(S)/F(S)'$ and $\pi_R:F(S)\to F(S)/\langle R\rangle$ be the natural projection with $\ker\pi_R=\langle R\rangle$ . Then by the universal property of commutator subgroups, we have the following commutative diagram:

[image]

Then by the universal property of free groups, the diagram below also commutes:

[image]

Combining them I get

[image]

But I do not know how to continue this work to obtain a group homomorphism as desired between the two abelian groups $F(S)/\langle R\rangle$ and $G$ .

Comment: Please avoid using images to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post. [Here is why](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742). (In particular, your images show way too large in my current display). I know that MathJax isn't great for commutative diagrams (plain $\LaTeX$ isn't great either), but there are ways to do commutative diagrams here. But [there are ways to do it](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2325/742).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for your advice, I had spent half an hour finding the way to draw diagonal arrows by AMScd in Mathjax before I posted my question, but it seems that there exists no way to draw a long diagonal arrow, so I had to use tikzcd to draw one instead.

Comment: The result looks awful on at least two of my devices. Way too large, and on very noticeably different enlargement scales for each of the three images. Which is just *one* of the problems with images: they cannot be scaled like the rest of the website. I don't know if they look ok to you, but they definitely do **not** look ok to me. They make your post harder to read and understand. I suspect a short diagonal arrow would have been a much better solution.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin It looks ok on my phone but it is too large on my computer. Next time I will directly show the universal property by text.

Answer (score 2):

**Lemma.** The normal subgroup of $F(S)$ generated by $R$, $\langle R\rangle^{F(S)}$, is precisely $[F(S),F(S)]$.

*Proof.* Since $R$ is generated by elements of $[F(S),F(S)]$, then we have $\langle R\rangle^{F(S)}\leq [F(S),F(S)]$.

Conversely, using the commutator identities (I use the convention $[a,b]=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$; similar identities hold for the other convention), we have:
$$\begin{align*}
[x,zy] &= [x,y][x,z]^y\\
[xz,y] &= [x,y]^z[z,y]\\
[x,y^{-1}] &= [y,x]^{y^{-1}}\\
[x^{-1},y] &= [y,x]^{x^{-1}}
\end{align*}$$
it follows that any element of $[F(S),F(S)]$ can be written as a product of conjugates of elements of the form $[s,t]$ with $s,t\in S$, so $[F(S),F(S)]\leq \langle R\rangle^{F(S)}$, giving equality.

(Alternatively, you already proved that $[F(S),F(S)]\leq \langle R\rangle^{F(S)}$ using the universal property of the abelianization, but I figured one universal property at a time is enough). $\Box$

**Proof of the Universal Property.**

*Existence*. Let $G$ be an abelian group, and let $\varphi\colon S\to G$ be a set map. Then there exists a (unique) morphism $\Phi\colon F(S)\to G$ such that $\Phi\circ i = \varphi$, where $i\colon S\to F(S)$ is the inclusion of $S$ to the free group on $S$.

Now we have a morphism $\Phi\colon F(S)\to G$, where $G$ is abelian. Therefore, there exists $\Psi\colon F(S)/[F(S),F(S)]\to G$ such that $\Phi=\Psi\circ\pi$, where $\pi\colon F(S) \to F(S)/[F(S),F(S)]$ is the canonical projection. But $[F(S),F(S)]=\langle R\rangle^{F(S)}$, so the domain of $\Psi$ is actually $A(S)$. Note that the inclusion of $S$ into $A(S)$ is $\pi\circ i$. Thus, we have a morphism $\Psi\colon A(S)\to G$ such that
$$\Psi|_S = \Psi\circ (\pi\circ i) = (\Psi\circ \pi)\circ i = \Phi\circ i = \varphi,$$
as desired.

**Uniqueness.** If $F\colon A(S)\to G$ is such that $F\circ (\pi\circ i) = \varphi$, then $F$ and $\Psi$ agree on $S$; since $A(S)$ is generated by $S$, it follows that $F=\Psi$, as required. $\Box$

Comment: Oh, you are knowledgeable in group theory. But I don't understand the superscript $y$ in $[x, yz]=[x, y][x, z]^y$ in the proof of your lemma.

Comment: @DianWei $x^g=g^{-1}xg$; ${}^{g}x=gxg^{-1}$.

Comment: There is a typo in $[x,yz]=[x,y][x,z]^y$ , replace $[x,yz]$ by $[x,zy]$ then it truly holds.

Comment: Your statement reminds me that $\langle R\rangle$ is just the closure by subgroups, and $\langle R\rangle^{F(S)}$ is the closure by normal subgroups, they are not the same in the case that $\#S=2$ : $\langle R\rangle$ is finitely generated but $\langle R\rangle^{F(S)}$ is not.

Comment: @DianWei Typo fixed. As to the other comment, I do not see how it is relevant to my post or why you decided to add it here.

Comment: Before studying your proof I misunderstood that $\langle R\rangle$ and $\langle R\rangle^{F(S)}$ were the same from [The generator set of the commutator subgroup of a free group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510055/the-generator-set-of-the-commutator-subgroup-of-a-free-group) , hence I wrongly thought there was a proper containment $F(S)'\subset\langle R\rangle^{F(S)}$ , but in fact it is $F(S)'\subset\langle R\rangle$ .

Comment: @DianWei Both proper inclusions are incorrect.

Comment: Oh, the latter proper inclusion is $\langle R\rangle\subset\langle R\rangle^{F(S)}$ for $\#S>1$ , i was so careless...